# software detecting each other in lan

Tags: security, vb6, lan

I have just developed a software in vb6, and almost ready for deployment, I need one feature.

As a way of curbing multiple installation in a network, i want the software to detect if another copy is installed within the same subnet, or lan network or all subnet belonging to one network.

Can you give me ideas on how to implement this feature?

i know i might probably use winsock for the network stuff, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IPv4 broadcasting or IPv6 multicasting to send a packet to a group (being all) of computers on the same subnet.

Comment: i don't understand anything about broadcasting in ipv6 or ipv4, so can you give me sample code on the subject or where i can learn about it

Comment: @Oghenero: This [link](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/networking/guide/netbroadcasting.html) would give you some of the theory. I don't know of any good sample, but and you try searching for the string `vb6 ip broadcasting` there's quite a few results, some which might contain some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

People could easily circumvent your proposed security measure by turning on the Windows Firewall. The best anti-piracy measure would be to move from VB6 to a Web Application hosted on the cloud.. google SaaS.

Comment: how do i implement this on a desktop application?